# Improved Eulers method with systems of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Got a question about applying Improved Eulers method to systems of differential equations. if given the differential system:

$\frac{dy}{dt} = t + y^2$

$\frac{dx}{dt} = x + 2y$

The question asked to use 1 step of improved eulers method to estimate $x(1)$ and $y(1)$. What i am having trouble with is figuring out how to apply the equations of improved eulers method to x and y to figure this out, I know that for one equation:

$y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{h}{2}(m_1 + m_2)$

with

$m_1 = f(t_n, y_n)$

$m_2 = f(t_{n+1}, y_n +hf(t_n,y_n))$

Im just strugging to appply these general equations in to two space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your ODE system in its vector form, i.e.,
$$
\frac{{\rm d}\mathbf{x}}{{\rm d}t}=\mathbf{f}(t,\mathbf{x}),
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{x}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}
\right)\quad\text{and}\quad\mathbf{f}(t,\mathbf{x})=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x+2y\\
t+y^2
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The improved Euler method, or a *[second-order Runge-Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)*, then reads
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_{n+1}&=\mathbf{x}_n+\frac{h}{2}\left(\mathbf{m}_1+\mathbf{m}_2\right),\\
\mathbf{m}_1&=\mathbf{f}(t_n,\mathbf{x}_n),\\
\mathbf{m}_2&=\mathbf{f}(t_{n+1},\mathbf{x}_n+h\mathbf{f}(t_n,\mathbf{x}_n)).
\end{align}

Comment: show how do you find the x value from that?

Comment: @TomHeeley: Did not get your point... What do you mean by the $x$-value?

Comment: In the question we have to use the improed eulers method to approximate both the y value and x value of t = 1

Comment: @TomHeeley: Yes, but what are your $x_0$, $y_0$ and $h$? Also, does your "use one-step of improved Euler method" mean to use $x_1$ and $y_1$ to approximate $x(1)$ and $y(1)$ respectively? In addition, all you need to do is to substitute these quantities into the vector form. Could you have a try for this?

Comment: Yes i will that helped alot thank you

Comment: @TomHeeley: Any time :-)